# Find File by substring in java

Tags: java, file, subdirectory

I'm having little trouble here. I have to find all the file inside a directory that **can contain** a certain word. Now i don't know how to operate, i can only find Files that Have the word as name but it's not enough for me.

```
 String path ="C:\...ecc...";
 String fileName= "01";
 File file = new File(path+fileName)

  if(file.exists()){
  // stuff with file
  }
```

This find the file that has 01 has name, instead i want to find all the files wich have 01 inside their name. Any ideas?

Comment: Share your code

Comment: Are you talking about filenames or file contents?

Comment: what is the trouble you are having? what have you tried?

Comment: Are you asking about a File to have the ability to contain a certain word?

Comment: Have a look at Apache Hadoop or Spark

Comment: Ironically, "I'm having little trouble..." means "I'm having no trouble...", at least where I am :)

Answer (score -4, accepted):

You should use this code-

```
File file=new File("D://folderName");
File files[]=  file.listFiles();
for(File f:files){
    if(f.getName().contains("search word")){
        System.out.println(f.getName());
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I found a solution (with a little help of Alok Singh):

```
   Boolean exist = false;
     for(File file : listaFile){                                    
        if(file.getName().startsWith(valueDeep)){
            path+="/"+file.getName();
            attachFileAnagView.setLvl3(file.getName());
            exist = true;
            }   
     }  

    if(!exist){
        new File(path+"/"+valueDeep).mkdir();
        path+="/"+valueDeep;
        attachFileAnagView.setLvl3(valueDeep);
    }
```

If the directory doesen't esxists, it create a new one.